# Found com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0, but version 8.3.0 is needed for the google-services plugin

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

Can't use google maps because of above said error. Anyone find the same issue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Version conflict updating to 8.4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370603/version-conflict-updating-to-8-4-0)

Comment: If you're using for only gmail authentication verify [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370603/version-conflict-updating-to-8-4-0/38355760#38355760)

Answer (score 114):

Make sure that the following line is **at the end of the app build.gradle** file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Mine was on the top and gradle was defaulting to 8.3.0 instead of what was specified: 8.4.0

My build.gradle files are the same as the ones in the [Version conflict updating to 8.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370603/version-conflict-updating-to-8-4-0)

Comment: Wow, this works.  But is so strange to apply a plugin at the end of the build.gradle file!  I haven't seen an example of this anywhere else.

Comment: Not only that but notice the plugin itself generates this line if it isnt at the end of the file: "please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the build file.". Therefore this is the correct solution.

Comment: This works. One of the pleasurable things of working with command line is those error details make sense. AS is a headache when it comes to fixing gradle issues

Comment: @DatNguyen: I think what you're saying is it's more of a kludge than a hack, then. As Raymond Chen might ask, "What if two programs did this?"

Comment: I guess these things can happen once you have stateful build description files.

Answer (score 27):

As those previous anweres are only part-wise complete.
Here are my three steps which worked fine for me:

1. Put this to the end of your **apps `build.gradle`**

   > `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
2. Set your **projects `build.gradle`** dependencies to

   > `'classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha5'`
3. Set **Gradle Version to 2.10**

   > Android Studio: *File > Project Structure > Project*

Comment: I was able to use it in the apps `build.gradle` and it worked

Answer (score 20):

> @redsonic's answer worked for me.. By simply **moving `apply plugin:
>   'com.google.gms.google-services'` after the dependecies** in
>   build.gradle (Module: app)

I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1 with Gradle version 2.10

In case you are using Gradle version older than 2.10 you'll also need to update that by selecting the ProjectName or app directory in the Project tool Windows and pressing F4. This will open Project Structure window, select Project from the menu and update Gradle version to 2.10. Press OK (Android Studio will download it in background).

build.gradle (Project: ProjectName)

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
}
```

build.gradle (Module: app)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: you must put - apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  after dependencies block. Otherwise it won't work...

Answer (score 5):

This is a slight variant of @Lord Flash's answer:

For me it wasn't necessarily that I should place the google services plugin at the bottom of the file it was that it should come before the `com.android.application` plugin.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Also there are newer binaries than the alpha variants for google-services

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta6'
    }
}
```

I'm sure there will be newer ones soon. I found the list of variants [here](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)

Answer (score 2):

follow all the steps at this link [Add App Invites to Your App](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/guides/app)

use this : compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.4.0'

instead of this : compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'

please follow all the steps and then build the project

hope thats help

Comment: @yuen shi , did you try it ?!

Comment: I combined Yuval and @Amer Hadi's solution and now issue is solved.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I found that moving:

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

To the bottom of the module app gradle.

and then use:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0'`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that some of your app dependencies that start with **com.google.android.gms:** have a version that is incompatible your project dependencie classpath **'com.google.gms:google-services:**

Check for these on your app build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
```

And for this in your project build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0'
```

You can update your project build.gradle to use the latest google-services version or your can just change your app dependencies to use the 8.3 version.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to        all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}

// this should solve the gradle update error if it persists even after following above steps
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the following line is at the end of the app build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
```

google update there API day by day.Now mine is '11.0.2'
try with the updated API