# Google Play Services in Android

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I try to implement google play services for the google cloud messaging. I tried to do this with [developers.google](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client), but i can not go futher. I get stuck by Set Up Google Play Services. I tried to compile com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0 but I get this error message:

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 8.3.0.

So i tried to compbile 8.3.0 and then i get a other error message:

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Good luck recovering your project.

Comment: Please provide the all the gradle settings related to the `com.google.android.**`.  I think you have compiled two play-services plugin with different versions.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help with the second error you had, but can hopefully help with the google services plugin error. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35188079/5938290), Lord Flash lists a few necessary elements to get the plugin to work correctly. Namely:

1. Put this at the **end** of your apps build.gradle

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
   ```
2. Set your projects build.gradle dependencies to

   ```
   'classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta5'
   ```

   (or whatever the newest version is)
3. Set Gradle Version to 2.10 - this was the key step for me to get everything working.

   ```
   Android Studio: File > Project Structure > Project
   ```

Hope it works for you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the info Hatchet, I edited the answer to be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer from [UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798816/unexpected-top-level-exception-com-android-dex-dexexception-multiple-dex-files)

> If you do not need all the google play services library dependencies
>   STAY AWAY from this line in your build.gradle compile
>   'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0' and instead just use what
>   you need!!