# Updated gradle to 2.10 and now travis can't find my tests

Tags: java, android, travis-ci

I guess this is travis-ci support? I was sent here from their website. I guess I should ask the question here.

So I'm adding Google Analytics to my app, and to do that I had to update gradle to version 2.10 for their plugin. After I finished it all travis-ci ran my build, but I get the following error on every build:

```
com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > No tests found.[test(AVD) - 5.0.2] FAILED
```

This wasn't an issue when I was using gradle2.2.1.-all.

To update I changed the `distributionUrl` in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

Anyone know a fix to this? All my other branches are fine, where I did not make this change.

For reference here is my travis.yml, I didn't change anything to it, just updated gradle.

```
language: android
jdk: oraclejdk7
android:
  components:
    - platform-tools
    - tools
    - build-tools-23.0.2
    - android-23
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-21
    - extra-android-support
    - extra-android-m2repository
    - extra-google-m2repository
    - extra-gooogle-google_play_services

env:
  global:
    - ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=8
    - MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2

sudo: false
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.gradle/caches/2.8
    - $HOME/.gradle/caches/jars-1
    - $HOME/.gradle/daemon
    - $HOME/.gradle/native
    - $HOME/.gradle/wrapper

before_install:
  - export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk
  - export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
  - echo "sdk.dir=$ANDROID_HOME" > local.properties

notifications:
  slack: caketechnologies:pnmNEHM1ZxudlMZNTv6oVgcT

install:
  - TERM=dumb ./gradlew -s assembleDemoDebug

before_script:
  # Create and start emulator
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-21 --abi armeabi-v7a
  - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &

script:
  - ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest -PdisablePreDex --stacktrace
```

Answer (score 5):

This is my .travis.yml file. Download gradle 2.10 before you start the build since it's not in Travis yet.

```
language: android
jdk:
    - oraclejdk8
env:
  matrix:
    - ANDROID_TARGET=android-21 ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
  global:
    - ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=8
android:
  components:
    - build-tools-23.0.3
    - android-23
    - add-on
    - extra
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-21
before_script:
    - wget http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-bin.zip
    - unzip gradle-2.10-bin.zip
    - export GRADLE_HOME=$PWD/gradle-2.10
    - export PATH=$GRADLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: btw, if you use gradlew then you don't have to manually download it.  Check  here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Comment: Adding the before script to specify the version of gradle to use really solved this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**these suggestions don't solve the issue, ignore this response**

You are using android gradle plugin 1.5 but you updated yesterday google play services plugin to 2.0.0.x to support google-services.json for different productFlavors. They updated both from 1.5 to 2.0.0.x [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/commit/79ff19f07ea6fe3bb3142f2953cb6ae699b8a00a). I would try to also update android gradle plugin to 2.0.0.x like here:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta6'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta6'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Last update:**
I'm not using this plugin version, perhaps updating gradle plugin versions to 2.0.0.X like [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/analytics/build.gradle) solves the issue.

[Google just included support for flavors on version 2.0 of the play services plugin. Since this version of the gradle plugin com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34364376/1009132)

And without the PATH changes on Travis-ci, I tried it one time, and they already export their default location, I'm not sure now, but it was an issue for me, and I added new location at the beginning.

**Update:**

Due this answer doesn't solve the issue, extra suggestions:

- Is your local build working after adding 2.10? [Google-services plugin config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35188079/1009132)
- Build `./gradlew build connectedCheck -PdisablePreDex --debug`
- Update [Android Gradle plugin version](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility)
- I suggest adding more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27084948/com-android-builder-testing-connecteddevice-hasteststestavd-5-0-failed) `--debug` so you can read the real reason
- Change [skin](https://github.com/travis-ci/docs-travis-ci-com/pull/466)
- Use ./gradlew clean assemble -PdisablePreDex
- Add the new exports to the beginning of the PATH, so are found before the default

**First answer:**

Perhaps you need [clearing-caches](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/#Clearing-Caches) or change this line:

```
- $HOME/.gradle/caches/2.8
```

by

```
- $HOME/.gradle/caches/
```

I guess you should comment out the next lines to discard caching related issues:

```
sudo: false
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.gradle/caches/2.8
    - $HOME/.gradle/caches/jars-1
    - $HOME/.gradle/daemon
    - $HOME/.gradle/native
    - $HOME/.gradle/wrapper
```

Comment: I tried this, deleted caches on travis website and commentated out the cache bit in my .yml but got the same error when running the build.

Comment: Perhaps is the first suggestion, Gradle plugin version < 1.5 requires gradle version < 2.10, what version are you using?

Comment: I'm using gradle version 1.5.0, just trying some of your suggestions now.

Comment: Now I'm getting the following error when running a build using clean assemble: File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.

That's annoying because I added it to each productFlavor and it works fine. Only on travis is fails.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using it, perhaps another can help you, good luck, I found this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866061/file-google-services-json-is-missing-from-module-root-folder-the-google-service

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, updated my gradle plugin to 2.0.0-beta6, but still getting the same error. Wish Google not force people to use google-services if it's still in beta.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, use gradle wrapper (aka gradlew). Travis use gradlew if available.

[Chapter 5. The Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)