# Android - Google Login and Play Services version incomptablity

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin

I'm having a weird issue with Google Login and Google Play services. 
I followed the instructions here https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating and added `'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'` to my build.gradle file.

I then added these play services libraries that we need for our app in the app's gradle file:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'`

But when I compile I get this error:

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>     Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 8.3.0.
> - Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.4.0, but version 8.3.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.

What confuses me is that the developer docs say to use version 1.5.0-beta2 plugin and version 8.4 play services but gradle will not let me compile.

Comment: Here is solution from google official app: - app gradle: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/build.gradle - project gradle: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/build.gradle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This post here has the answer [Version conflict updating to 8.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370603/version-conflict-updating-to-8-4-0/34375483#34375483)

I needed two things,

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha5'`

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha5'`

and to move apply plugin: `'com.google.gms.google-services'` to the end of the file