# Google Sign-in button error in Android

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-plus-signin

I try to include Google sign-in button in my android app by following steps:

1) Including the button:

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

2) Editing  Top-level build file

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
```

3) Editing App-level build file

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Now I am getting error in button UI as

> Blockquote
>   The following classes could not be found:
>   - com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton (Fix Build Path, Create Class)

Please help me solve this issue!

Comment: You need to include google play services in the app gradle file

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' is it enough? @Shmuel

Answer (score 2):

First of all we need to clarify that you should have 2 `build.gradle` files. One of them is a project-level file and the other one is an app-level Gradle file:
[image: gradle files]

These files should look like this:

`Project: StackOverlfow` build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

`Module: app` gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.package"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
}
```

If you don't have Google Play Services installed, please do the following:

1. Go to Android Studio -> Preferences -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Android SDK. 
   [image: sdk manager]
2. You'll see on the bottom part a "Launch Standalone SDK Manager".
3. Click that and you'll have the standalone SDK Manager window opened.
4. Scroll all the way down to "Extras" pick "Google Play Services" and hit update.
   [image: GPS]

This will install the proper play services packages. Once done, go back to the Android Studio and re-sync your Gradle file.

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 8.3.0.

Comment: It seems like you need to update Google Play Services from the SDK manager too. Go to Android Studio -> Preferences -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Android SDK. You'll see on the bottom part a "Launch Standalone SDK Manager". Click that and you'll have the standalone SDK Manager window opened. Scroll all the way down to "Extras" pick "Google Play Services" and hit update.

Comment: The plugin you use is wrong. Please revisit my answer's details and try that you have "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'" where you have "apply plugin: 'com.android.application'"

Comment: Same Revision 29 only :(

Comment: I used both :
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: Please check the updated answer. You should be good to go with this.

Comment: The 1.5beta2 build is what is giving him an issue here. He needs to use the 2.0alpha build of the gradle plugin

Comment: I just built a working example with 1.5beta2 and the setup I just added. Am I missing something?

Comment: That error he got "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at bintray.com/android/android-tools/…) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 8.3.0. –"  is fixed by updating the gradle plugin. I don't know why your build works, I was just commenting that I faced the issue he has and fixed it in that manner.

Comment: i think Shmuel is right? I updated the code and it needs gradle 2.10 so i am downloading it now

Comment: Give it a try, sure! It might be the case, but like I said with the gradle setup I have in the answer, I managed to run an app and use the SignInButton

Comment: Now new error 
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my question over here - [Android - Google Login and Play Services version incomptablity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801520/android-google-login-and-play-services-version-incomptablity)

You need:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha5'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha5'
```

and

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
```

Also, Google's sample here was helpful to me 
https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/appinvites/app/build.gradle