# Android Studio rendering error with Google Play sign-in button

Tags: android, android-studio, google-authentication

I'm trying to utilize Google Play's sign-in button (as seen in [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) tutorial) by adding the following code to the activity xml:

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

But it results in the following error in the preview window under "Rendering Problems":

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not resolve resource value: 0x7FFF000C.
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:932)
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:919)
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getDrawable(Resources_Delegate.java:165)
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getDrawable(Resources_Delegate.java:139)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:738)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaf.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaf.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.setStyle(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:186)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:334)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:345)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:245)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$53(RenderTask.java:659)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Update your google-play-services-lib to the latest version

Comment: [This](http://i.imgur.com/wKPAfjs.png) is what I have installed, Google Play services is at its latest version.

Comment: See this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35022859/google-sign-in-button-error-in-android) It might help you.

Comment: The answers found at that link tells me I need to have the google-services classpath in my top-level gradle file and compile play-services-auth in my app-level gradle file. I have both of these, at their latest versions.

Comment: Solved. Turns out I had to build again.