# java.lang.VerifyError when initial LocationServices

Tags: android, google-play-services

I update the Google play service SDK (Rev 29) in Android SDK Manager recently.
Then I found the apk I build after the SDK is updated will crash during initial the GoogleApiClient.

Here is the code we use.

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
```

And here is the log of call stack

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.xxxxxxx.xxxxx, PID: 3855
java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd because it failed compile-time verification (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd' appears in /data/app/com.xxxxxx.xxxx-2/base.apk)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices.(Unknown Source)

The google play service version I use is **com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0**

Answer (score 1):

I try to update Location service to 8.4.0.
But it cause [Version conflict updating to 8.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370603/version-conflict-updating-to-8-4-0).
So I follow the instruction in the above link.
Then the problem solved.

Here is the instruction I use.

1. change to use **compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'** in app build.gradle
2. move **apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'** to the end of app build.gradle
3. use **classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'** in project build.gradle dependency
4. change to use **gradle-2.8** in gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties