# Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have Android project and when run `./gradlew dependencies` command, I get the following error and I cannot figure out how to use Google Play Service 8.4.0. (8.3.0 works)

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.jar
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.pom
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.jar
         https://zendesk.artifactoryonline.com/zendesk/repo/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.pom
         https://zendesk.artifactoryonline.com/zendesk/repo/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.jar
         file:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.pom
         file:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.jar
         file:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.pom
         file:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.jar
```

Here is how the app gradle file looks like.

```
  dependencies {
      ....
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
      ....
  }
```

I have've tried to put the following in a project gradle file but didn't work help.

```
    dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'
    }
```

Could anyone help me to debug further?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
> > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
> >     Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0.

Post your total `build.gradle`

1. **Use Latest versions of build tools**
2. Then call classpath `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'`

Finally

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

Check **[Version conflict updating to 8.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370603/version-conflict-updating-to-8-4-0)**

Comment: Sorry, this was my customer's project, so I was hesitant to put the whole gradle file.

Comment: This answer works for me. Besides the answer, I noticed that installing `build-tools-23.02` was failing. After installing 23.02 and modify the grale files, then the dependencies was successfully installed.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like Google subsumed many libraries under `Google Repository`. **Install `Google Repository` and the `Android Support Repository` via the SDK Manager** and gradle should be able to resolve the libraries. Here my `gradle.build` file for comparison:

```
buildscript {
    repositories { jcenter() }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
  repositories { jcenter() }
  compileSdkVersion 24
  buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'
  dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem also. It would be the missing of following packages in the Android SDK:

- Android Support Repository
- Google Play services
- Google Repository

If you are using the [Android SDK command line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#download) `sdkmanager`, you can run following command to install the related packages:

```
sdkmanager "extras;android;m2repository"
sdkmanager "extras;google;m2repository"
sdkmanager "extras;google;google_play_services"
```

Answer (score 1):

you need

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

you have download that in sdk manager

and change that in `build.gradle`

and i use this in build.gradle project side

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
```

Answer (score 0):

also add this line to your app level gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
dependencies {
      ....
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
      ....
  }
```

Comment: another thing also update your google play service from sdk manager