# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. in Android Studio

Tags: process, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I have got following error while adding dependency in build.gradle

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 8.3.0.
```

I have added following dependency and plugin to build.gradle(app level) to integrate GCM 3:-

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0"
```

build.gradle(Top Level):-

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
```

Your advice will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370603/version-conflict-updating-to-8-4-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After debug and search in google I came to know that I have added dependency of google play service in build.gradle with two different versions.

Remove the older one solves this issue

Thank you

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Open app level build.gradle file and find the google play service and remove the lower version. In my case I have added version 8.4 and 9.0, I have just remove the 8.4 [delete that line] and do SyncNow. Another way is Right Click to your Project > Open Module Setting > Select apps from Modules > Click on Dependency Tab > Select Lower version dependency > Click on - icon from right top corner > Click on Ok.