# What I can know what dependency version I need compile with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have the next gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'


    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.4'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.3.0'

    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0-rc1'

}
```

I'm getting error in the lines starting with: `compile 'com.google.android.gms`

The error is:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>
> > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
> >     available at
> >     https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
> >     or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 8.3.0.

How I can know what version are available for this specific component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep the version of `com.google.android.gms` libraries the same. If you are going to use v. 8.4.0 for the services.base, then you should always keep the others the same. So, you should also set services-location to the same version:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
```

See [Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project) for more version information.

Also, here is a similar question that is helpful for general Gradle setup as well: [Version conflict updating to 8.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370603/version-conflict-updating-to-8-4-0)